# How do I print out the specific index?

Tags: python-3.x, list, lis

My code: text = [['Name', 'Surname', '2009']]

What I tried to do: text[1];

I want so that the 'Surname' would print out, but I keep getting - IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You have a list *of list*. `text[0][1]` would be `'Surname'`.

Comment: This is a list within a list. so text[0] will give you the inner list then you need [1] to acces sindex 1 of the inner list. So text[0][1] says access the list in index 0 or text then access surname in index 1 of the inner list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nested list.

```
text = [['Name', 'Surname', '2009']]

text[0] = ['Name', 'Surname', '2009']

text[0][1] = 'Surname'
```

Comment: thanks, can you also help me how can I sort the date with sort() if let's say, there is 2014, 2005 and 2009?

Comment: Use dates.sort() to sort in ascending order.